# Subjunctive and imperative

Tags: grammar

I understand some subjunctive rules, but when the subordinate clause doesn't have a subject I don't know how to combine the sentence.
Could you please check it to me? Is it possible to combine like this?

> This is advisable. **Do not permit** our competitors to know our plans.
>   This is advisable **that do not permit** our competitors to know our plans.
>   This is imperative. **Get** your passport renewed before you leave the country.
>   This is imperative **that get** your passport renewed before you leave the country.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This is advisable. Do not permit our competitors to know our plans.
>   This is advisable that do not permit our competitors to know our plans.
>   This is imperative. Get your passport renewed before you leave the country.
>   This is imperative that get your passport renewed before you leave the country.

You **cannot** use the second and fourth forms. If you wish to use the subjunctive to express a command with no commander (person giving the command), you can only ever use *It* as the subject of the matrix (outer) clause.

Additionally, a clause embedded by *that* must be well-formed, subjunctive (*which is essentially identical to the declarative in modern English*) clauses: it must have a subject, a finite verb, and objects/obliques if necessitated by the verb.

Although "you" may mean the person you are writing for/to or addressing, it can stand for "one", and is probably more idiomatic than "one" in modern English. Since "you" is number-agnostic, it is safe to use.

I would also consider that the first and third sentences are unusual in their Theme-New structure - you refer to **this** but you introduce **this** in the next sentence. While cataphoric reference is perfectly legitimate, the information flow is unusual, and particularly so in the first example.

I would write those sentences as:

> Do not permit our competitors to know our plans. This is advisable.
>   It is advisable that you do not permit our competitors to know our plans.
>   Get your passport renewed before you leave the country. This is imperative.
>   It is imperative that you get your passport renewed before you leave the country.

---

The comments resulting from this Q&A have raised important points that are worth raising as an addendum:

- In Modern English, the subjunctive isn't really as productive as it is in other languages - the only verb that obligatorily conjugates differently in such constructions is *be*, and even this is phasing out.
  All other verbs can take the infinitive (minus *to*), but it is perfectly acceptable to use the declarative in these senses. (For instance, either *We demand that Tom hire her immediately* or *We demand that Tom hires her immediately* could be said,)
- These "subjunctive" clauses are everyday, straightforward *declarative* clauses - they have a subject and finite verb like any other.

  - @StoneyB has said that because these often express mandates, it can be useful to think of the as *imperative* clauses. I would argue this is true **only** to the extent that the meaning can be imperative. Imperative clauses, however, do not generally have finite verbs or subjects (with the exception of *let's* and third-person subjects, as in *Chocolate lovers rejoice!*).
- In short: it may be easier to think of these constructions as merely two clauses -  *clause + clause* - since they don't require any special treatment. *Subjunctive* makes things confusing, and is a relic of the past (or analogised from other languages), and has little or no place in today's English.

Comment: +1 Do you perhaps mean *cataphoric reference*? And I'd say that the 'subjunctive' is essentially identical to the *infinitive* or *imperative*, since it does not inflect for person and with one verb, *be*, is distinct from the plain form.

Comment: @StoneyB Well, in these cases, other languages might have a subjunctive mood that results in different verb conjugations; as you've said, in English only _be_ is distinct from the plain form. However, it is perfectly acceptable and probably more idiomatic to use the usual forms of _be_ in everyday language, resulting in sentences that are declarative - if you look at the embedded clauses, they're all declarative, simple present. It's not the infinitive as most would understand it, lack _to_, nor the interrogative, since it contains a subject, and would not be well-formed without it.

Comment: @StoneyB but yes on the cataphoric reference.

Comment: I incline toward identifying it as the imperative, at least for pedagogic purposes,since this 'subjunctive' is employed today exclusively in mandative clauses, and that's a convenient way for students to remember.

Comment: @StoneyB have you found that to be effective, though? Imperative clauses have no subject (with the exception of _us_), which looks like what could have happened in the OP's original sentences. I suppose a distinction needs to be made between the syntactic sense and the semantic sense of "imperative". Also, would you say that _it's crazy that you still haven't taken that job_ is subjunctive (and does it even matter)?

Comment: Effective? I dunno. As for *It's crazy &c*, this is precisely why I object to the term 'subjunctive' for contemporary English (there's a bit more justification in EME): that's a subordinate clause but it takes the ordinary indicative (*...that you aren't taking that job*). I prefer *irrealis* for what traditional grammar calls 'past subjunctive' and *imperative* or *infinitive* for what traditional grammar calls 'present subjunctive'. But as you say, it doesn't really matter what you call it.